# AWS RDS VPC Connection Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I really tried hard...I have a RDS MySQL Instance. Its security group is configured with MyIP such that I can access it with MySQL Workbench without any problems. Now I add to the SG my Elasticbeanstalk instance SG just as I do successfully with another Elasticbeanstalk Instance and another RDS DB. In both cases I use the JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING parameter. I ran out of ideas why one beanstalk/RDS pair works fine while the other doesn't. I even deleted the RDS instance and created a new one but to no avail. When I have the server output the connection string it is correct. Using the other RDS instance (via the JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING parameter), the server connects successfully to the other DB (whose SG was added this S2 instance SG). The 2 connection strings only differ by the DB name. Any idea highly apprechiated!

Comment: I think you should probably post this question @ www.serverfault.com instead of here.

Comment: All servers and databases are in the same VPC?

Comment: Yes, all instances are in the same VPC. The DB server log says " [Warning] IP address '172.xxx.xxx.xxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known" so it doesn't appear to get the internal connection. @Christian thanks, will try that.